# How to solve 403 Forbidden While sending HTTP POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I m gettin 403 Forbbiden Error while sending this request. I have ALLOW CORS plugin working. How Can i solve that problem

JavaScript

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("signupbtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:9000/user/register?username="+username+"&password="+password);
    xhr.send();
  })
</script>
```

```
signup.html:53     POST http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=a&password=a 403 (Forbidden
```

Comment: HTTP status 403 has nothing to do with CORS. Check the code or documentation of the backend, that should tell you why you're getting an error. Perhaps your username or password is incorrect?

Comment: Make sure that the register and login actions allow for anonymous calling

Comment: This sends the username and password to add user on database

Answer (score 0):

403 means Forbidden. Maybe your backend expects something more like some kind of authentication/authorization.

Please check the documentations of your api carefully.
Hope it solves quickly. Best of luck.